# Spark (pyspark) having difficulty calling statistics methods on worker node

Tags: python, macos, apache-spark, pyspark

I am hitting a library error when running pyspark (from an ipython-notebook), I want to use the `Statistics.chiSqTest(obs)` from `pyspark.mllib.stat` in a `.mapValues` operation on my RDD containing (key, list(int)) pairs.

On the master node, if I collect the RDD as a map, and iterate over the values like so I have no problems

```
keys_to_bucketed = vectors.collectAsMap()
keys_to_chi = {key:Statistics.chiSqTest(value).pValue for key,value in keys_to_bucketed.iteritems()}
```

but if I do the same directly on the RDD I hit issues

```
keys_to_chi = vectors.mapValues(lambda vector: Statistics.chiSqTest(vector))
keys_to_chi.collectAsMap()
```

results in the following exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-80-c2f7ee546f93>", line 3, in chi_sq
  File "/Users/atbrew/Development/Spark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/stat/_statistics.py", line 238, in chiSqTest
    jmodel = callMLlibFunc("chiSqTest", _convert_to_vector(observed), expected)
  File "/Users/atbrew/Development/Spark/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 127, in callMLlibFunc
api = getattr(sc._jvm.PythonMLLibAPI(), name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

I had an issue early on in my spark install not seeing numpy, with mac-osx having two python installs (one from brew and one from the OS) but I thought I had resolved that. Whats odd here is that this is one of the python libs that ships with the spark install (my previous issue had been with numpy).

1. Install Details

   - Max OSX Yosemite
   - Spark spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6
   - python is specified via spark-env.sh as
   - `PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python`
   - `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH:$EA_HOME/omnicat/src/main/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/`
   - alias ipython-spark-notebook="IPYTHON_OPTS=\"notebook\" pyspark"
   - PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS='--num-executors 2 --executor-memory 4g --executor-cores 2'
   - declare -x PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="ipython"

Comment: After a bit more digging, I see that this is bascally `sc` (spark context) is `None`, when the exceptions is thrown. Does this mean the worker nodes in pyspark do not have access to the `sc` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noticed in your comment the sc on the worker nodes is None. The SparkContext is only defined on the driver node.

Comment: Is this meant to be the case? It seems a real limitation of the Statistics class not to be able to distribute this calculation out to the worker nodes (especially for something like a chi-squared calc on a vector, and extra important because I want to distribute this calc ;)). Is this just a limitation of pyspark or would I face the same issue if I implemented in scala?

Comment: This is intentional with the SparkContext. In general, most of the stastics functions are meant to work on RDDs in which case they are only callable on the driver (and if we look at the doctests in the code we can see that it is only tested on rdds). Because of how the executors are setup, its not super easy for them to call java functions. I'm not sure if this code was intended to be callable from inside of executors or only from the driver, you could file an issue for this to make it callable on the executor but I'm not sure how much work would be involved in setting up the py4j bridge.

Comment: Thanks, I see now. I'll file a request as you suggest and see what comes back. I see the use case of applying the function on an RDD its not fullfulling my need here.  Though It probably just make more sense to use scipy [scipy.stats.chisquare.html](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) inside the workers.