# PySpark DataFrame of model statistics cannot be collected or converted to RDD

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I'm encountering confusing PySpark errors when trying to extract the threshold value associated with the highest recall value from the DataFrame returned by `recallByThreshold`. Interestingly, these errors only occur when running the application in cluster mode.

```
training, testing = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3], seed=100)
train = training.coalesce(200)
test = testing.coalesce(100)
train.persist()
test.persist()
model = LogisticRegression(labelCol='label',
                           featuresCol='features',
                           weightCol='importance',
                           maxIter=30,
                           regParam=0.3,
                           elasticNetParam=0.2)
trained_model = model.fit(train)
threshold = trained_model.summary.recallByThreshold.rdd.max(key=lambda x: x["recall"])["threshold"]
```

The final line of code produces `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setCallSite'`. Broken down further, when I attempt `trained_model.summary.recallByThreshold.rdd` I get another a different error `*** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sc'`.

This problem appears related to [Spark (pyspark) having difficulty calling statistics methods on worker node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998543/spark-pyspark-having-difficulty-calling-statistics-methods-on-worker-node), but in this case I'm not able to collect the DataFrame at all (produces same error). I launched my application from IPython on the master node, so shouldn't the `SparkContext` be available through the `SparkSession` (using Spark version 2.1.0)?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27335?jql=text%20~%20%22setcallsite%22